# Why ALPN only support android 4.4+?

Tags: http2

I want use `HTTP/2` for `Android 2.3+`, but I found that `Okhttp` only supports 5.0 and above cause `ALPN` only supports on `Android 4.4+`.

Any way to support it for `Android 2.3+`?